# Compiling and running java application using powershell

Tags: java, powershell, powershell-2.0, javac, powershell-3.0

I am trying to compile and a sample Helloworld.java file.
I have my jdk installed in C:\Program Files\jdk1.7\bin.

And I have my Helloworld.java in C:\Helloworld.java

I am actually a novice in both powershell and java.
I got some examples from web regarding this but many of them advice to run it like this:

> java.exe -classpath $Env:CLASSPATH C:\Helloworld.java

But when I give this in powershell I get an error called 'CLASSPATH' is not defined even after adding it in env variables.

And when I try to compile the code with the following syntax:

```
$javac C:\Helloworld.java I get an error "javac is not recognised as a token".
```

So, I am literally lost in this topic . Any step by step procedure to run java programs using powershell for dummies like me will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but gradle seems the way to go -- at least for now.

Answer (score 5):

Setup environment variables in your system.

set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\jdk1.7`

add to `PATH` variable the string `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

open new `cmd` session.

navigate your java source folder.

use `javac` to compile your java files.

**UPDATE:**

also if you are experiencing difficulities upon launching an executable via PowerShell check this [Microsoft TechNet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Comment: I am able to compile and run it through the cmd prompt, I want to do it using powershell scripting only

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, you have PATH variable set properly and javac is available to execute from any folder and you get the error that javac is not found when you try to exec javac via PowerShell. Am I right?

Comment: I have updated my answer, check the update please, there's a link to [microsoft technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx) where it is explained how to run executables via PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

The variables you speak of do not exist in PowerShell as you name them.

The correct variable names are

```
$Env:JAVA_HOME: C:\jdk1.6.0;

$Env:PATH: C:\jdk1.6.0\bin;.;

$Env:CLASSPATH: C:\jdk1.6.0\lib;.;
```

As they all must be defined in the ENV: PSDrive

Answer (score 0):

To answer it in a much simpler way , its the path problem .

You probably not have set env variables that's it.

This is how you should set it:

```
JAVA_HOME: C:\jdk1.6.0;

PATH: C:\jdk1.6.0\bin;.;

CLASSPATH: C:\jdk1.6.0\lib;.;
```

And later if you open a cmd prompt and type java -version , if you are able to see the java installed version then you are good to go.