# Ensuring files are available to the JVM

Tags: java, netbeans, tensorflow, jvm

I'm trying to install TensorFlow for Java on Windows 10 using this [Article](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java#advanced_example)
. I followed the steps carefully but the windows commands didn't work with me so I decided to do it manually.

The first command is to make the .jar part of the classpath and I did it manually

but the second step was to ensure that the following two files are available to the JVM: the .jar file and the extracted JNI library

but I don't know how to do that manually

The code:

```
package securityapplication;

import org.tensorflow.TensorFlow;
import org.tensorflow.Graph;
import org.tensorflow.Session;
import org.tensorflow.Tensor;



public class SecurityApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (Graph g = new Graph()) {
      final String value = "Hello from " + TensorFlow.version();

      // Construct the computation graph with a single operation, a constant
      // named "MyConst" with a value "value".
      try (Tensor t = Tensor.create(value.getBytes("UTF-8"))) {
        // The Java API doesn't yet include convenience functions for adding operations.
        g.opBuilder("Const", "MyConst").setAttr("dtype", t.dataType()).setAttr("value", t).build();
      }

      // Execute the "MyConst" operation in a Session.
      try (Session s = new Session(g);
           Tensor output = s.runner().fetch("MyConst").run().get(0)) {
        System.out.println(new String(output.bytesValue(), "UTF-8"));
      }
    }
  }

}
```

could someone help? cuz my program that uses TensorFlow  still have the following error
[image]

The text in the image is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot find TensorFlow native library for OS: windows, architecture: x86. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java/README.md for possible solutions (such as building the library from source). Additional information on attempts to find the native library can be obtained by adding org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.DEBUG=1 to the system properties of the JVM.
at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:66)
at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:66)
at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.init(TensorFlow.java:36)
at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:40)
at org.tensorflow.Graph.<clinit>(Graph.java:194)
at securityapplication.SecurityApplication.main(SecurityApplication.java:15) Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

The result after running the first command in cmd:

[image]

The result after running the second command in Windows PowerShell:

[image]

Any suggestions?!

Thank you

Comment: That build output is so tiny it’s nearly unreadable.  Please include text output as text (preferably in an indented preformatted block), not as an image.

Comment: is this the result of : javac -cp libtensorflow-1.3.0.jar HelloTF.java ?

Comment: @VGR I did that. Thank you

Comment: @Tom No brother. The commands didn't worked with me I did this step manually where I paste the libtensorflow-1.3.0.jar file in the same directory of HelloTF.java  and rerun the code then this result appeared. I don't know how to do the next step manually without using the commands in the article

Comment: if you are not using an IDE like eclipse that'll do the building for you, I guess you'll have to compile the java file, in order and prior to run it. When you say the command didn't work with you, what were the outputs  ?

Comment: @Tom Yes I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.4. I'm not sure if I did that correctly. I run those commands on windows PowerShell. The result of the second command will be included in the question

Comment: can you try follow the TF guide by using the cmd prompt and not the windows PS ? You can use PS but if you do make sure to follow this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464295/compiling-and-running-java-application-using-powershell

Comment: @Tom I used cmd for the first command as suggested and the result included above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155362/discussion-between-tom-and-f-505).

Comment: You have a space after `-D`. It must be a single command line option, i.e. without any space characters in-between: `-Djava.library.path=the_actual_directory`

Answer (score 0):

The first command failure (`javac`) suggests that the `javac` command is not in your `PATH` environment variables. See for example, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678520/javac-not-working-in-windows-command-prompt)

For the second command failure, I believe the space after `-D` is what is causing you trouble as Holger suggested.

IDEs like Eclipse and others also provide a means to set the `java.library.path` property for the JVM (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957700/how-to-set-the-java-library-path-from-eclipse) for example).

Background: TensorFlow for Java consists of a Java library (packaged in a `.jar` file) and a native library (`.dll` on Windows, distributed in a `.zip` file). You need to ensure that the `.jar` file is in the classpath and the directory containing the `.dll` is in included in the `java.library.path` of the JVM when executing a program.

Hope that helps.