# How to use javac in powershell?

Tags: java, powershell, javac

*I'm entering this-*
javac HelloAll.java

*and getting this error-*

javac : The term 'javac' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1

- javac HelloAll.java
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javac:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

*What's going wrong here? Please tell how to fix it. (I've already installed JDK)*

Comment: Looks like a path problem. You may refer this to set correct path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464295/compiling-and-running-java-application-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

It means that the **javac.exe** executable file, which exists in the **bin** directory of the JDK installation folder is not added to the **PATH** environment variable. You need to add the **JAVA_HOME/bin** folder in your machine's PATH to solve this error. You cannot compile and run a Java program until your add Java into your system's PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

This means javac.exe don't add to PATH variable .
open : Control Panel -> System -> advanced System settings -> environment variables -> User variables for admin -> double click on PATH environment variable and copy the value and delete values next .
find the path that you install java there . replace it in path variable with add the \bin;
to path variable . and next of this paste copied values .

try :

java  , javac , appletviewer